# Rails CMS for a multilingual site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, multilingual

A client wants a multilingual site with a CMS. Is there a Ruby on Rails CMS out there that can deal with that out-of-ze-box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://adva-cms.org/

Best Rails CMS I've seen so far. It also has German, French, Spanish, English locales built in.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I thought I would give some additional updated information, because there are definitely more than one Rails CMS with multi-language support:

- [adva-cms](http://adva-cms.org/wiki)
- [radiant](http://radiantcms.org/)
- [refinerycms](http://refinerycms.com/)
- [webiva](http://www.webiva.net/forum/new/user-and-integrator/56/140)
- [zena](http://zenadmin.org/en/features#i18n)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Ubiquo + ubiquo_i18n plugin

http://guides.ubiquo.me/edge/ubiquo_i18n.html

The integration is pretty extensive (e.g. you can have common images for all the translations or independent images per translation), and you can create scaffolds with out the box i18n capabilities.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers :)